# Remove window.location.href from click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

according to current media query i am doing a div clickable. If does not matches max-width: 767px then i am binding the url of the anchor. But if matches the query i do not want to do anything on click. Is there a way to remove it on the else... ?

```
   if (!window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        jQuery(el).addClass("clickable");

        jQuery(el).click(function (e) {
            window.location.href = jQuery(el).find("a").attr("href");
        });
    }else{
        jQuery(el).removeClass("clickable");

        jQuery(el).click(function (e) {
            window.location.href = ??????
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move click event outside the `if` condition - it will be easier to handle.

```
var result = !window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches;

jQuery(el).click(function (e) {
    if (result) {
        window.location.href = jQuery(el).find("a").attr("href");
    }
}).toggleClass("clickable", result);
```

Or just use `unbind` method:

```
var clickFunction = function (e) {
    window.location.href = jQuery(el).find("a").attr("href");
};

if (!window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
    jQuery(el).addClass("clickable").click(clickFunction);
} else {
    jQuery(el).removeClass("clickable").unbind('click', clickFunction);
}
```

Comment: hm on else it correctly removes the clickable class but it still redirecting me on click

Answer (score 0):

If it is the case you can not edit the code, you can override functionality by adding relevant code after it.

```
   if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        jQuery(el).removeClass("clickable");
    }
```